# mp4 is not working in safari

Tags: javascript, safari, mp4

Mp4 is not working in safari with relative path, it's working fine in all others browsers except safari, but when I tried to play the same video in safari it gives this error :

> Unhandled Promise Rejection: NotSupportedError (DOM Exception 9): The operation is not supported

What actually I want is to play a video after clicking on play now button but it's not working, also when I give absolute url of any online video it works in safari also.

Comment: If you paste the url of this video in the address bar, do you get anything?

Comment: Thank you for your support but the issue is already resolved.

Comment: @RohitKumarVashisht Can you please let me know How did you solved it because I having same issue?

Answer (score 0):

Safari does not support relative URLs for media playback.

It's an undocumented bug.